# Why is my C++ OpenGL program not rendering a simple rectangle on screen with no errors from OpenGL debugging context?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

**SOLVED!**
Here is how I solved it (thanks to G.M. for providing the answer and the explanation)

```
Apart from anything else glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); is incorrect: vertices in this context decays to a pointer. You probably meant glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesSize, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); . Likewise for the EBO
```

(comes from G.M.)

Basically when you use a pointer in C++ it will not return the correct array size, you actually need to pass your array size in your function parameters.

So I modified the following code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

to:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesSize, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesSize, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

So basically I am new to OpenGL and I tried a small program (inspired by tutorials) to render a simple rectangle on screen (using VAO, VBO and EBO).
I have turned OpenGL debug context on, but I get no errors or warnings.

Here is the graphical result:
[Nothing, just the yellow clear color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBK26.png)

Here are my console logs:

```
vShaderCode: #version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
fShaderCode: #version 330

out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

vertex: 1
fragment: 2
ID ('1): 3
ID ('2): 3
ID ('3): 3
0
FPS: 76 Updates:29
FPS: 74 Updates:30
```

Here are my files:

(I decided to not include some .h files for my classes, because I don't think they are related to the question)

**Main.cpp** (just used to run the program, nothing special here)

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include "WindowManager.h"

WindowManager windowManager;

int main()
{
    int code = windowManager.preInit();

    if (code != 0) {
        return code;
    }

    windowManager.gameInit();
    windowManager.gameLoop();
}
```

**WindowManager.cpp** (a class which manage GLFW window and some basic game loop)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "ErrorChecker.h"

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void WindowManager::processInput()
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int WindowManager::preInit()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
   // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, true);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    primaryMonitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();

    mode = glfwGetVideoMode(primaryMonitor);
    SCR_WIDTH = mode->width;
    SCR_HEIGHT = mode->height;
    aspectRatio = (float) SCR_WIDTH / (float) SCR_HEIGHT;

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "BlockyUniverse", primaryMonitor, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);

    int flags; glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);

    if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT)
    {
        // initialize debug output 
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
        glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugOutput, nullptr);
        glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
    }

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    return 0;
}

bool initialized = false;

void WindowManager::gameInit()
{
    masterRenderer.init();
}

void WindowManager::gameLoop() {
    std::cout << initialized << std::endl;

    static double limitTPS = 1.0 / 30.0;

    double lastTime = glfwGetTime(), timer = lastTime;
    double deltaTime = 0, nowTime = 0;
    int frames = 0, updates = 0;

    // - While window is alive
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        // - Measure time
        nowTime = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime += (nowTime - lastTime) / limitTPS;
        lastTime = nowTime;

        // - Only update at 60 frames / s
        while (deltaTime >= 1.0) {
            WindowManager::update();   // - Update function
            updates++;
            deltaTime--;
        }
        // - Render at maximum possible frames
        WindowManager::render(); // - Render function
        frames++;

        // - Reset after one second
        if (glfwGetTime() - timer > 1.0) {
            timer++;
            std::cout << "FPS: " << frames << " Updates:" << updates << std::endl;
            updates = 0, frames = 0;
        }

    }

    cleanUp();

    glfwTerminate();
    return;
}

void WindowManager::update()
{
    
}

void WindowManager::render() 
{
    // Input
    processInput();
    //controls.tick(mainRenderer, *window);

    // Render
    masterRenderer.render();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

void WindowManager::cleanUp(){
    masterRenderer.cleanUp();
}
```

**MasterRenderer.cpp**

```
#include "MasterRenderer.h"

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void MasterRenderer::init()
{

    float vertices[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // top left 
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
    };

    masterShader.init("shader.vs", "shader.fs");

    object.init(vertices, sizeof(vertices), indices, sizeof(indices));
}

void MasterRenderer::render()
{
    glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    object.render(masterShader);
}

void MasterRenderer::cleanUp()
{
    object.cleanUp();
}
```

**GameObject.cpp** (here goes the most important part (drawing an object on screen)

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "Shader.h"

void GameObject::init(float vertices[], unsigned int verticesSize, unsigned int indices[], unsigned int indicesSize)
{
    cachedVerticesSize = verticesSize;
    cachedIndicesSize = indicesSize;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // remember: do NOT unbind the EBO while a VAO is active as the bound element buffer object IS stored in the VAO; keep the EBO bound.
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
    // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
    glBindVertexArray(0);

}

void GameObject::cleanUp()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}

void GameObject::render(Shader& shader)
{
    shader.use();

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cachedIndicesSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

**Shader.h**

```
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Shader
{

private:

    unsigned int ID;

    // utility function for checking shader compilation/linking errors.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if (type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if (!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

public:
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void init(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath, const char* geometryPath = nullptr)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::string geometryCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        std::ifstream gShaderFile;

        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        gShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();

            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();

            // if geometry shader path is present, also load a geometry shader
            if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            {
                gShaderFile.open(geometryPath);
                std::stringstream gShaderStream;
                gShaderStream << gShaderFile.rdbuf();
                gShaderFile.close();
                geometryCode = gShaderStream.str();
            }

        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure& e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;

        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");

        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");

        // if geometry shader is given, compile geometry shader
        unsigned int geometry;
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
        {
            const char* gShaderCode = geometryCode.c_str();
            geometry = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(geometry, 1, &gShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(geometry);
            checkCompileErrors(geometry, "GEOMETRY");
        }

        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();

        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glAttachShader(ID, geometry);
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");

        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);

        if (geometryPath != nullptr)
            glDeleteShader(geometry);

    }
    // activate the shader
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }
    // utility uniform functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setBool(const std::string& name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setInt(const std::string& name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec2(const std::string& name, const glm::vec2& value) const
    {
        glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec2(const std::string& name, float x, float y) const
    {
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec3(const std::string& name, const glm::vec3& value) const
    {
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec3(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z) const
    {
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setVec4(const std::string& name, const glm::vec4& value) const
    {
        glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, &value[0]);
    }
    void setVec4(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z, float w) const
    {
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), x, y, z, w);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat2(const std::string& name, const glm::mat2& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix2fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat3(const std::string& name, const glm::mat3& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void setMat4(const std::string& name, const glm::mat4& mat) const
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
    }

};

#endif
```

**shader.fs** (Fragment Shader)

```
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

**shader.vs** (Vertex Shader)

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Apart from anything else `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` is incorrect: `vertices` in this context decays to a pointer.  You probably meant `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesSize, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` .  Likewise for the EBO.

Comment: Thank you G.M., that was the error, my rectangle is now rendering correctly! I will edit my answer and provide your solution and your explanation. Thanks again! I should be more careful next time...